# Mismatched anonymous define() only when using uglified version of code

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS for an angular app, in the default yeoman webapp structure.

One of my scripts needs to take an array for which scripts to load because we conditionally load one of several modules at once.

The raw code works fine - produces no errors, properly loads the module dynamically;

```
var requireModules = ['history'];
define(requireModules, function(){

  return angular.module( 'myApp.moduleLoader', /* dynamic array used here */ );

});
```

However, when the grunt/usemin/build process concats/uglifies all the code, it looks like:

`var requireModules=["history"];define(myApp,function(){return angular.module("myApp.moduleLoader" ...`

Which then produces this error:

`Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return angular.module("myApp.moduleLoader"`

Comment: I am curious, did you figure this one out? I'm having the exact same problem, although I'm not using angular, I'm using breeze and knockout. Havent managed to figure out which script is causing the issue at this point. My error message is: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return t(e)}

Got any tips?

Comment: Nope, never did. Sorry

Comment: My problem was with breeze, so I avoided it by not minifying it